# Passing arguments or using providers in Flutter

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

Which method is preferable in Flutter: using a Provider or directly passing values to the next page?

I'm wondering which approach is better suited for transferring data between Flutter pages. I'm debating whether to use a Provider to centrally manage data and make it accessible across the app, or simply pass the values directly to the next page. What are the pros and cons of these approaches? Are there specific scenarios where using a Provider is preferred, and others where directly passing values is more practical?

I'd appreciate advice and insights from the Flutter community. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Are there impacts in terms of performance?

Comment: If the flow is unidirectional, args are often easier.  If the data has to be updated by a routed page, state management is preferred.

Comment: if you have very simple app,  and no nested page : passing arguments are fit for you. But when it become more complex, reactive page: you have to use state management,

Comment: Thank you!
Well, that is the question - is it complex or simple. As a beginner it is hard for me to estimate what the appropriate approach is. To give you an idea: In the end I want to have three tabs where two of them will have three nested pages (startpage -> some list page -> final overview page). Giving what you wrote @pmatatias that would be considered complex already such that state management would be the better approach?

Comment: Giving what you said @RandalSchwartz, however, args might be better given that I only need to pass arguments in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. For simple data in a limited scope, directly passing values between pages is sufficient. If your app grows in complexity or if you need to manage data across multiple screens, using a Provider would be a more structured and efficient way to handle state.

Comment: Also you can use some service locator, for example https://pub.dev/packages/get_it. Just for me - it's better and easier when passing args or using provider.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage in terms of using providers for all of these things? Like do they impact the performance negatively or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

data management is very important. you have to understand the data flow between screen and modules.

my preference is like this:

- if i have 3 modules that access user profile data. so i have to put user profile data to state management. since 3 modules could possibly change the user profile data
- then when i have search screen which contain date time filter (from date and to date), then i have to show the result on **new screen** then also **showing the date filter on result screen** like "filtering date x to date y". the data update happened one sided (the result screen don't have the right to update the data). in this case, you need to pass the arguments

bonus: when passing arguments, i make class to make things easier

```
class InvoiceResultViewArgs {
  const InvoiceResultViewArgs({
    required this.viewEnum,
    required this.from,
    required this.to,
  });

  final InvoiceViewEnum? viewEnum;
  final DateTime? from;
  final DateTime? to;
}

class InvoiceResultView extends StatefulHookConsumerWidget {
  const InvoiceResultView({
    required this.args,
    super.key,
  });

  static const String routeName = '/invoice_result_view';
  final InvoiceResultViewArgs args;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _InvoiceResultViewState();
}
```

somewhere on routes file:

```
  if (settings.name == InvoiceResultView.routeName) {
    if (settings.arguments is InvoiceResultViewArgs) {
      InvoiceResultViewArgs args =
          settings.arguments as InvoiceResultViewArgs;

      return InvoiceResultView(args: args);
    }

    return const MissingArgumentView();
  }
```

this will makes things a lot easier and clean
also i use riverpod, makes it even cleaner

just makesure that you separate business logic and data..